# How to get the aggregate result only on the first occurrence, and 0 to the other, in a computation with groupby and transform?

Tags: python, dataframe, transform

I would like to groupby and sum dataframe, without modifying the number of indexes but applying the operations to the first occurrence only.

Initial DF:

```py
C1 | Val
a  | 1
a  | 1
b  | 1
c  | 1
c  | 1
```

Wanted DF:

```py
C1 | Val
a  | 2
a  | 0
b  | 1
c  | 2
c  | 0
```

I tried to apply the following code:

```py
df.groupby(['C1'])['Val'].transform('sum')
```

which it helps to propagate the aggregated results to the total number or rows. However, it does not seem that [transform](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) have arguments which allow to apply the results to first or last occurrence only.

Indeed, what I currently get is:

```py
C1 | Val
a  | 2
a  | 2
b  | 1
c  | 2
c  | 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `pandas.DataFrame.groupby`:

```
s = df.groupby('C1')['Val']
v = s.sum().values
df.loc[:, 'Val'] = 0
df.loc[s.head(1).index, 'Val'] = v
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  C1  Val
0  a    2
1  a    0
2  b    1
3  c    2
4  c    0
```